# Why is Heroku installing rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

This is what I have in my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '= 2.4.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "cucumber-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "redgreen"
  gem "faker"
  gem "remarkable_activerecord"
end
```

When I do

```
git push heroku master
```

on my screen this is what I see

```
Installing rspec-core (2.5.1) 
Installing rspec-expectations (2.5.0) 
Installing rspec-mocks (2.5.0) 
Installing rspec (2.5.0)
```

I thought Heroku installs in production mode, then why rspec is being installed?

Answer (score 5):

That's because by default all groups are installed. To tell Heroku to ignore certain groups, run

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

You can read more about [using Bundler with Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler) if you wish.